# Why use ConfigurationManager vs reading custom configuration file?

Tags: c#, configuration

I've always used my own format of configuration files which is XML and then I just deserialise the XML into an object in my project or just read it into an XML document.

This seems alot easier to read and access the information I need.

I've had a look at the `ConfigurationManager` class this morning and it seems a bit overly complicated just to read a config file.

Is there any argument as to why I should use `ConfigurationManager`?

Comment: Settings in a web.config can be edited visually via the IIS manager  - that's one bonus. Generally though, I find ConfigurationManager very easy to use. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 4):

1. It is just a built-in mechanism in .NET which is *already* implemented for you, so you don't need any extra code (probably except for wrapping it in your own `IConfig` to separate concerns).
2. There is a GUI for editing .NET configuration files which sometimes comes in handy.
3. ASP.NET application, for instance, automatically restart when `web.config` has been changed, while you would need some custom logic to have the same behaviour with your own config files.

Answer (score 2):

The ConfigurationManager is used internally and you're not obligated in any way to use it, and I used to do what you do. Nowadays it depends, if it is a file a user is supposed to change I might still do my own configuration, otherwise the file is added as an embedded resource and I use the ConfigurationManager to read it, because I don't think there is another way of reading those files. The thing is, use whatever mechanism you feel like, ConfigurationManager provides a bit more encapsulation though and out of the box utils classes.